# do spoofed packets get dropped?

Tags: networking, ip, router

I need to spoof the IP source address of some packets in order to perform some experiments. Should I expect those packets to be dropped?  What's the common practice here for routers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all really depends on the router, some routers do ingress filtering, which may drop your packet. See more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingress_filtering

Comment: OK. So I shouldn't really make use of IP spoofing if such packets don't always get through.  One question, though: can ingress filtering happen anywhere along the path, I mean could ISPs at any tier level do this?

Comment: I don't know how common it is to to this, but yes. This could be done anywhere in the network. It's easier to implement "closer to the originator" (you) since the closer you get, the easier it is to determine if the origin is valid.